# Xamarin forms App behavior is different in Release mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin Form app crashes on release mode, however when its in debug mode, it works perfectly.

I have created a Xamarin form app using MVVM and many WCF calls. The below mentioned are the problems I have faced in release mode:

```
- Login page: The page loads without binding the the value from Viewmodel. And when clicked on Login, app does not crash. It will be still showing the login page

- Inner page with service call- Changed the app start page to innerpage to further check what is happening and the issue is that the app does not even start. The page has a service call on start.
```

Have disabled shared runtime in manifest
I have deleted the obj and bin folder.

Comment: This is a common issue , which is caused by  different reasons . So you should provide more details such as error log.